# How to start a .gif file from the first frame in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, gif

I'm using two `.gif` files and switching them in a frame.

```
private Image currentGIF;

if(x == 0) gif = "image1.gif"
if(x == 1) gif = "image2.gif"
ImageIcon reference = new ImageIcon(gif);
currentGIF = reference.getImage();
```

--

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D graphic = (Graphics2D) g;
    graphic.drawImage(gif, 0, 0, this);
    g.dispose();
}
```

--

```
@Override   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
{
    repaint();
}
```

And this is my problem:

1. `image1.gif` starts at the first frame.
2. `image2.gif` starts at the first frame.
3. `image1.gif` starts at a random frame.

It seems the `.gif` keeps running and when I show `image1` again it doesn't start at the first frame.

Comment: You may also want to have a look at [`Image#flush`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#flush())

Answer (score 2):

Issues:

1. Never override a JFrame's paint method, but instead do your drawing within a JPanel's paintComponent method.
2. Never dispose of a Graphics object given to your painting method (paint or paintComponent) by the JVM as this breaks the painting chain.
3. Don't change the state of your GUI (for example swap images) within a painting method. Instead do it within a listener of some type that reacts to the event that you want to use to make the image change -- such as a button's ActionListener if it's to change on button press, or a Swing Timer's ActionListener if the image is to change on timer change.
4. If this is not an animated GIF, strongly consider making the image into an ImageIcon and simply swapping the icon of a JLabel using `setIcon(...)` again with the listener that you desire to use.